# How to count occurrences of specific element for arrays in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

How can I count for the occurrence of certain integer in a list with few arrays? For example I would like to look for the occurrences of the value 2.

```
import numpy as np
a = [np.array([2, 2, 1, 2]), np.array([1, 3])]
```

Expected output:

```
[3, 0]
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `Counter`

```
In [3]: from collections import Counter
```

Gives frequencies of all numbers

```
In [4]: [Counter(x) for x in a]
Out[4]: [Counter({2: 3, 1: 1}), Counter({1: 1, 3: 1})]
```

To get count for only `2`

```
In [5]: [Counter(x)[2] for x in a]
Out[5]: [3, 0]
```

Alternatively, you could use `np.bincount` method, to count number of occurrences of each value in array of non-negative ints.

```
In [6]: [np.bincount(x) for x in a]
Out[6]: [array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)]
```

Extract counts for number `2`

```
In [7]: [np.bincount(x)[2] for x in a]
Out[7]: [3, 0]
```

Comment: x=[[array([-2,  0,  0]), array([-2, -1,  1])], [array([ 3, -1]), array([ 1, -2])]]. When applied to this variable x it returns error. Thanks. Your reply is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Counter is an excellent alternative. However, since you just need to check for a certain value within a nested list, perhaps a simple list comprehension would also work:

```
>>> [sum(b==2) for b in a]
[3, 0]
```

Comment: You make it further simpler with `[sum(b==2) for b in a]`?